# why do I get nan when using sklearn R2 function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am always predicting the next value with an `sklearn` model.

```
y1_test, y2_test, y3_test, y4_test = get_test_targets(df)

ypred1, ypred2, ypred3, ypred4 = ml_model(df, ElasticNet())
```

I would like to use sklearn to measure the r2 score of the `y_true` and `y_predicted`.

```
np.array([y2_test])
>> array([6.75233645])

np.array([ypred2[0]])
array([6.75233645])
```

Using `r2_score(np.array([y2_test]), np.array([ypred2[0]]))` gives `nan`

I do not understand why I am getting `nan`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a warning telling you what is wrong:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

x = np.array([2.3])
y = np.array([2.1]) # exact values do not matter

r2_score(x, y)
```

Result:

```
UndefinedMetricWarning: R^2 score is not well-defined with less than two samples.
  warnings.warn(msg, UndefinedMetricWarning)

nan
```

This should not be a surprise: the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) of R^2 is

```
R^2 = 1 - (total_sum_squares)/(residual_sum_squares)
```

but with only one sample both the nominator and the denominator of the fraction are 0, leading to a `0/0` division, which is indeed a `nan` (computationally, as well as mathematically).

Bottom line: you should not use only a single pair of data to compute R^2; batch together more pairs of predictions & ground truth samples in order to get meaningful R^2 results.